# Servo amplifier for DC motors

Tags: amplifier, pwm, dc-motor, servo, pll

I have an *Harmonic drive* and would like to design a PLL (phase-locked loop) controller for speed control of it. Here is a block diagram of a motor-speed control system based on PLL techniques:

[image: Pll motor speed control]

My Question is about **power amplifier (servo amplifier)** (see image above).

- What is best circuit for servo amplifier of DC motors?

Desired circuit must have poles at much higher frequencies than the poles of the motor. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need the amplifier to have its poles at much higher frequencies than motor's poles?

Comment: What power does the amplifier need to supply? What voltage and current ratings are required? What gain does the amplifier need to have? What is the lowest demanded speed and how many notches in the opto disc are there?

Comment: @VasiliyZukanov By considering this, the poles of designed amplifier can be neglected.

Comment: I don't know what Harmonic Drive is, but you wrote that it is a kind of DC motor. The function of this amplifier will be to supply (relatively) slow varying DC voltage to the motor, right? Two questions: 1. if the voltage is DC, then why do you care about the poles of the amplifier? 2. if the motor is DC, and the only input to the amplifier is a voltage signal from the filter, then why do you consider to use servo amplifiers?

Comment: @Andyaka Consider these ;
Rated Input Speed : 2000 (rpm)
Max. Input Speed : 4000 (rpm)
Max. Input voltage : 27 v / Max current : 6A
Output power : 100~150 W
The main problem is servo amplifier and number of notches is not important(consider motor speed measured by tachometer and known - Kz = 1)
The output stage of amplifier drives the motor.

Comment: @VasiliyZukanov You're right. Harmonic drive is a DC motor with non-linearity effects on it's model. But if your questions are apropos; we have some conflicts: remember the model of DC motor; we have one inductor ! (however the input voltage is DC)

Comment: I seem to lack some understanding of what you're doing. If 1. your motor is equivalent to a brushed DC motor; 2. the driving signal is DC (not PWM); 3. the rate of change in motor's speed is low; then I don't understand what is the importance of amp's frequency response. Furthermore, if you do not have any direct feedback from the motor to the amp, then why do you need a servo amp? Aren't these amps designed to take advantage of various feedbacks form a servo motors?

Comment: @VasiliyZukanov The driving signal is PWM. With this assumption what is your suggestion?

Comment: Then you want to take the output of Loop Filter and convert it to PWM? Why?

Comment: @VasiliyZukanov I think you are going to fallacy by your questions. If you have any ideas I'll grateful to you for sharing those.

Comment: @VasiliyZukanov From picture above it's obvious that driving signal is PWM (set point, shaft speed with w1 and tetha1). If you familiar with "phase frequency detector", you find out that there is a feedback from motor speed to servo amplifier.

Comment: I'm familiar with the theory of PLLs. However, the err signal from the PSD (which can be though as PWM) should be averaged by the filter to produce a DC signal for VCO (a motor in your case). When you say that your motor is controlled by PWM signal, I understand that the output of the filter (which is DC) is converted to PWM by the device you labeled as "power amp" on the diagram. This whole setup just doesn't makes sense to me. Either I misunderstand something, or you're not familiar enough with the concepts of PLL.

Comment: I am beginning to get the distinct "*in-over-your-depth*" feeling about this question and OP's subject knowledge now. Downvoting as "unclear" on that basis.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Oh! thanks for your downvoting. I hope to I can repay.

Answer (score 1):

> What is best circuit for servo amplifier of DC motors?

I'd use a PWM converter that feeds to a push-pull MOSFET output stage. You could probably use a power op-amp circuit but you'd be running it hot although it would still work. Your power supply should be OK if it can supply 30V at 6A. For a circuit I'd consider looking at the LT1160 data sheet. It has the following circuit for a 200W class D amplifier.

[image]

It needs checking what components other than the one I marked that needs bypassing to allow proper DC control but this would be a good starting point I reckon.

A pointer about terminology - a servo amplifier is more than a simple amplifier like what you have in your diagram. A servo amplifier takes the demand input and processes the feedback signal to ensure the motor is kept in closed-loop control

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_drive) has an article.

I also asked in my comment about the lowest speed demand and the number of notches in the disk. I asked to make sure you were properly accounting for low speed running in the loop filter.

Comment: Thanks, but could you give a schematic of circuit?

Comment: @Zia the LT1160 data sheet gives a decent circuit that would be convertable to your needs I think. Don't ask how to convert it - that would be asking too much - also try googling "Half bridge class D motor controllers". Circuit added to answer. It's also worth looking at this device if you can feed PWM directly http://www1.futureelectronics.com/doc/ANALOGICTECH%20-%20AATI/AAT4910IJS-DB1.pdf

Comment: Some experts believe we can't use class D for this case.
What is your opinion about this :
Using a trigger based controllable device like 6-phase or 12-phase rectifier(using SCR or IGBT)

Comment: @Zia show a circuit of what you mean but I'm not an expert on IGBTs or SCRs. Class D = PWM control.